# Creating a function to work out oddsratios

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am attempting to write a function that calculates odds ratios. The function must take as an argument a data frame with three variables ("female", "male" and "n") and four observations, and return the odds ratio.

```
df <- data.frame(female = c("White", "White", "non-White", "non-White"),
                 male = c("White", "non-White", "White", "non-White"),
                 n = c(85, 5, 5, 10))
# data represented as a table
xtabs(n ~ female + male, df)
# the odds ratio here is:
(85 * 10) / (5 * 5) 
#34
```

```
MyoddsRatio <- function(df){
  df <- df %>% 
  mutate(oddsratio = (n[1]) * n[4])/(n[2] * n[3]))
return(df)
}
```

To test if the function works I'd like to see it return an oddsratio of 34.

Comment: The bracket `)` after `n[1]` is not required. You're creating a column `oddsratio` here, and returning the whole `data.frame`. I think a single value is sufficient.

Comment: If you don't want to put a question online, please don't. Right now, there's no way to remove it unless the answerer deletes their answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe will always be in that format, you can use `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
MyoddsRatio <- function(df) {
  df %>%
    summarise(oddsratio = (n[1] * n[4]) / (n[2] * n[3]))
} 

MyoddsRatio(df)
  oddsratio
1        34
```